# Out vs outside in "Tell mummy we are going out to eat"

Tags: adverbs, phrasal-verbs

I decided to go out to eat.

I told my son.

> "Tell mummy we are going out to eat."
>
> "Tell mummy we are eating out."

Should I use outside or out in the context above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question relates to the following in the context of "we are going out(side) to eat".

> Out vs outside

Some definitions:

> **out** *adverb*
>   3.1 In or to a public place for purposes of pleasure or entertainment.
>   ‘an evening out at a restaurant’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/out)
>
> **outside** *preposition & adverb*
>   Situated or moving beyond the confines or boundaries of.
>   ‘I stepped outside the marquee for a breather’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/outside)

*Going **out** to eat / *eating **out*** suggests going to a restaurant, whereas *going **outside** to eat / eating **outside*** suggests remaining at the property but not in the dwelling itself (e.g. eating on the balcony).

Answer (score 1):

**First sentence:**
use *out* because you are using *out* as a part of phrasal verb not preposition.

**Second sentence:**
You can use both but I usually say *out* because it's shorter.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can eat outside without going out to eat, too. (In other words, you can walk outside your house and eat in the yard, say, at a picnic table.) So, yes, you can use both – but they don't mean the same thing.